# Box shadow does not work in Chrome, even with Webkit

Tags: css

Box shadow works in Firefox but not Chrome. Does anyone know how to fix this problem.

I tried adding the web-kit line as shown in my code below, but has no effect.

```css
#cv_photo
{

    border: 3px solid black;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px rgb(60 60 60);
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px rgb(60 60 60);  
}
```

I have included the full code below in case the problem is coming from elsewhere in the code:

```css
  #anchor_me
 {
    text-align: center;
 }


 #cv_photo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: 60px;
    display: flex;   
    z-index: -1;     

}

body
{
    background-image: url("IMG_89120.jpg");
    background-position: center

}

body
{
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

#anchor_me
{
    color: rgb(102,51,0);
}


#cv_photo

 {

    border: 3px solid black;
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px rgb(60 60 60);
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px rgb(60 60 60);  
}
```

Any help to fix the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't see webkit in your code.

Comment: You have an error in your color: the channels should have commas between them, like `rgb(60,60,60)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the rapid answer, that was in fact the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a colon to separate the RGB values
Try this:

```
#cv_photo{
    border: 3px solid black;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px rgb(60, 60, 60);
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px rgb(60, 60, 60);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,